# Can we plot Graphs on Kibana by custom Query on Elastic Search

Tags: elasticsearch, visualization, kibana, elastic-stack

I have a query with respect to building visualizations in Kibana.

I have already performed aggregations like uniq value over a period of time(say every 1 minute for 30 days) and saved it in Elastic Search. Now I want to plot this graph in Kibana

The problem I am facing is that Kibana is asking me to select a aggregation(like sum, uniq count,etc.) for Y-axis and select a field to apply the same.
On X-axis, I am having timestamp.

But since as mentioned above, I have already done the Uniq Count of my data set over timeperiod of 1 minute interval for a period of 30 days and stored it in Elastic Search, Hence I donot want Kibana to aggregate the data for me, rather just plot the data which I have in my Elastic Search.

Is it possible to just plot the data which I have in Elastic Search to Visualize in Kibana, but not aggregating them over there in my Y-axis?

If Yes How can I do so. Please advise on this problem of Kibana.

Thanks

Comment: I think you should take a look at [timelion](https://www.elastic.co/blog/timelion-timeline)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you are still struggling with this or not...

If you already have the data "summed up", then as you say, it is not necessary to tell Kibana (Actually Elasticsearch) to do the summing for you... this is true, if you are going to be plotting ONE minute time intervals. Over a period of 30 days is around (...) 43200 intervals... it is a LOT for charting. So kibana is going to suggest (strongly, and with a lot of sense) to use say, 30 minutes or even hourly intervals.

Now, if for instance you are grouping together events for a whole hour, then Elasticsearch is going to either SUM/AVG/MIN/MAX this 60 measurements and get a single value for that hour's plot.

So, my advice is that you select a Average Metric, and use common sense for the time lapse selection. That way you are going to have your chart, and if you really need to go to the minute by minute detail, you are go